# Booting issues from old computer

Tags: boot

I have an old computer that is about 6 to 7 years old. It works OK but in order to boot it I have to start it about 8 times, needing sometimes to unplug and replug it to make it work.

Otherwise when I push the power button it starts but without showing something in the monitor. Also, it doesn't show up the light from the tower, only the fans start running. I want to ask which is the most likely cause for these problems in those situations.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say, but it sounds like it could be a dry joint or the power supply failing (or a dry joint in the power supply which is failing!!).  What might be happening is the system is cold and an electrical connection is not working properly, but it starts working as the system heats up a bit.

Comment: Now I noticed that when unplugging it for a long duration will make the trick otherwise it will start but won't boot neither will show something on screen nor the tower will be lightened.So what might be the cause,I suppose I have the same problem with (http://superuser.com/questions/179401/old-pc-failing-with-no-beep-or-monitor-signal-at-start-up-but-occasionally-it-b?rq=1).Btw sorry for the delayed correspondence and thanks for your opinion.I shall try another PSU and see.

Answer (score 0):

Check the website badcaps.net for another possible answer to your question; also take a few minutes to read en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague

Best of luck with this; let us know how it turns out

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link didn't know it much appreciated, honestly you made me want to re-install some new caps.I 'll keep you updated if anything new :D , thanks again